# Cannot install vim plugin due to git problem

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug

I'm on MacOS Big Sur with nvim 0.7.2,vim-plug, and git 2.37.1 installed.

I succesfully installed [vim-crystal](https://github.com/vim-crystal/vim-crystal) (to enable syntax highlighting for [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/) codes) by doing this:

1. Edit `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
2. Add this line: `Plug 'vim-crystal/vim-crystal'`
3. Run nvim and then run `:PlugInstall`

Done. Open any Crystal code and it will be highlighted properly. Then I want to install [nim.nvim](https://github.com/alaviss/nim.nvim). Similar step: edit `init.vim` and add `Plug 'alaviss/nim.nvim'`. When I run `:PlugInstall`, I get this:

```
x nim.nvim:                                                                            
Cloning into '/Users/andre/.config/nvim/plugged/nim.nvim'...       
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

git issue? weird because those 2 plugins are fetched from github.com

How to fix this?

Comment: Is git functioning properly outside of Neovim?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/22147574/9447571 helps you solve the problem.

Comment: vim-plug has a workaround for this issue, see https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/56, but it seems recently they dropped this workaround for git 2.3.0+, using the `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` environment variable instead, see https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/161 for more details.

Comment: @JoseMembreno yep. I use it regularly for work.

Comment: NB This can occur if the plugin is misspelled or the repository doesn't exist